# Can data files be corrupted when writing ALTER DATABASE CONTROLFILE command?

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

Actually I am confused with the question and couldn't get easily on this question on my examination: "Consider you got a call from your backup DBA while you are on leave. He has corrupted all of the data files while playing with the ALTER DATABASE CONTROLFILE command. What do you do? Explain." What would be the appropriate answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `ALTER DATABASE CONTROLFILE` is not a valid command, at least you can use the `ALTER DATABASE BACKUP CONTROLFILE TO TRACE;` and i’ve never seen an Oracle Database broken by the command above.

Back to your question, a restore+recover is the only solution if that guy corrupted all the Datafile..

Now you have two scenario:

**1)** The DB is in archivelog mode and fully-backupped (daily), you would restore the database using the `set until_time`clause (to get closer to the last transaction possible) then `restore database` and `recover database` - all in a `run` rman block.

**2)** If it’s not, you would only issue the `restore database` command via rman, to restore your database at your last cold (offline) backup.

At the end of one of those steps, you need to  `OPEN DATABASE RESETLOGS` since you’re coming from what Oracle calls an “incomplete recovery”.

Forgot an important thing:

If that guy just currupted the datafile only, the steps above could save your life, if the controlfile(s) is/are broken for some weird reason, you need to `restore controlfile from [backup_name]` or `from autobackup` it, and then copy it in the other locations (if any) OR you would need to recreate it/them from the ground up.

Hope this helps.

***For the sake of it:***

```
SQL> alter database controlfile;

ERRORE alla riga 1:
ORA-02231: opzione di ALTER DATABASE mancante o non valida
```